# Adding outer class button click to selenium

Tags: css, selenium

Could someone help me in accessing outer class buttons?

That's the part of the code which is marked by firebug upon clicking the button
`<a class="link_view_more" href="/photos/albums">View all</a>`

Comment: I'm sorry, but i really dont understand the question.

Comment: My point here is that the button is managed by outer class and since I cannot get any attribute (id, link) I am not quite able to add "click" action for my automatic tests in selenium

Comment: Can you not access it via the "link_view_more" class that is attached to the link?

Comment: Well I am totally new to selenium so I don't know many possibilities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not able to click on the link having class name as link_view_more. You can try this :

```
selenium.click("//a[@class='link_view_more']")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the A by its classname using javascript's `getElementsByClassname`. See: http://help.dottoro.com/ljpxmhgp.php

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/XZH2e/

For future reference:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var anchors = document.getElementsByClassName('link_view_more');
    console.log(anchors[0].style.color = 'red');
​</script>
```

Once you have the anchors array, you can use that to attach your events.

Comment: I'm afraid it won't' run under selenium ide